# How do I display access database in VB?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

So I have been able to connect my database to VB forms, and I am also able to see the table and the fields within. But I can't figure how to make the data appear in the table because it's just blank.

I do have some data stores in the actual access database but it won't show up in my program.
Is there a particular code I need to write? This is what I have so far. The database is called the 'POS system'.

```
Private Sub OrdersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OrdersBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.OrdersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.POS_systemDataSet)

    End Sub
```

Comment: What's "VB Forms"? Do you mean "Windows Forms"?

Comment: The code you have posted is to save changes back to the database. It's hard to believe that you actually looked for information on how to retrieve data and couldn't find it. Such information would be all over the place. In fact, if you drag a table from the Data Sources windows onto the form, it's even generated for you. In short, you need to call Fill on the appropriate table adapter to retrieve data.

Comment: There are so many different examples around on how to query access databases both on this site and elsewhere.  Expectations here are you do your own reading before asking here

Comment: @HamzaAsim Ok, I will accept that my response wasn't particularly helpful with your problem.  However, it is still valid feedback that you should be taking on board, this site does demand a certain level of quality and effort in questions.  Your question is really unclear as to what exactly your issue is, compounded by seemingly unrelated code.  You need to learn to ask the right question to get the right answers.  This will avoid your questions getting down voted

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a good idea to separate your database code from your user interface code. Create a connection and a command in a `Using` block so they will be closed and disposed at `End Using`. Pass the connection string to the constructor of the connection. Pass the `CommandText` and connection to the constructor of the command. Open the connection and execute the command returning a DataReader to load the DataTable.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = GetData()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Function GetData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * From SomeTable;", cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a good answer because, based on the code in the question, the OP already has a typed DataSet. Suggesting taking data access code out of the form is fine but that code should still use that typed DataSet.